# Invalid scope type 'containers_stores' in Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3, product-listing

In Magento 2.3.3 on going to the listing page, it's showing an error like `main.CRITICAL: Invalid scope type 'containers_stores' [] []` and because of that my listing page getting blank. I followed this issue https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/1361 for it doesn't help. So how do I overcome this issue?

Comment: did you check in luma theme ? if same is happening in luma, there may be issue related to third party module

Comment: Yes I checked that but it's not working as well